# Flash AS2 hitTest not working properly

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, hittest

hope there are still a few people here which like me simply can not separate from Flash (and Actionscript 2). :)

I am trying to make a little adventure in Flash, but my hitTest doesn't seem to work properly. I have a Movieclip "Player" and various Movieclips as playfields, like "Plains". If the "Player" hits "Plains", my scene should "gotoAndStop" to the corresponding frame, also called "Plains". The "player" controls via a compass (click east and players x moves +20), the collision with the playfields is done by hitTest. See screenshots below.

My problem: Unfortunately the hitTest query works only with one of the game fields (the bottom one in the screenshot). Has anyone got an idea why that is? I am short of despair, already spent the whole weekend and simply can't find no solution.

Thanks in advance
krake82

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlquX.jpg)

Comment: Insufficient information. There's no telling which one of the objects is the player, which one is the feld_plains, and what is the hierarchy of the objects.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Organis. The purple circle is the "Player" and the two green fields are both "feld_plains" also with the instance name "feld_plains". The lower right star is the compass, which controls the player movement. When the Player hits one of the "feld_plains" flash should jump to frame 10, named "plains". If Player does not hit "feld_plains" it should jump back to frame 1, named "start". Hope that helped to clarify. Kind regards.

Comment: Do I get it right that you have 2 different objects with the same name?

Comment: Yeah, is that a problem? I wanted to build a map with the objects and of course would have multiple copies of "feld_plains", jungle, water, etc. I thought working with a variable and an if-query that it should work, no?

Comment: Well, you have two friends, both named Fred. You call "Fred!" Which one of them respond? You **can** have multiple copies of one Library object, but you should have a way to directly address each single one of them. If you give them same instance names only one of them will be available for you to work with.

Comment: Thats my problem. Both of them should respond and even with the same answer! But only one random one does. Dont i just need a code snippet that says, after the hit test with plains is triggered, to somehow unload the hittest so it can be triggered again when my next step lands on the same field?

Comment: Come up with a way to access them separately. Like, name them Field0, Field1, etc, and then hitTest each of them iterating them by name, or put them into Array, or whatever.

Comment: That would be very inefficient, since in the end there will be about 2500 fields on the game map.

Comment: Okeeeey, which is less efficient, inefficient way or the way that does not work at all? You have few options at this point, I think. 1. I advise to switch to AS3, it executes tens (sometimes hundreds) time faster than AS2. 2. Limit hitTesting objects by preliminary x,y check, or maybe, if applicable, by putting your obstacles into a grid so you will hitTest closest 3x3 cells. 3. Both.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a while (AS2) still use AS3 - but you can't have 2 movieclips on the screen with the same Name and call to all of them - like if you had a zombie - you would have to use zombie[1], zombie[2] - you could do this from an array.

The other way (not necessarily best but effective) would be to create a movie clip with code "in it" thereby making it sort of "self-sufficient" the code in the clip could react without using outside code (in most cases).